# Tomcat hosting a proxy webapp generates SSLHandshakeException after some time running correctly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ssl, tomcat, sslhandshakeexception

I have a web app deployed in Tomcat.  Part of that Web app is a proxy, written as a JSP that forwards requests to another URL.  The URL that is being forwarded is an HTTPS URL, so the proxy opens an HTTPS connection.  I have the certificate in the truststore in Tomcat's JVM.  The connections work fine for a day or so and then all of a sudden ( after maybe a day of it working fine ) it starts to fail consistently on all requests.  Restarting tomcat fixes the problem until about another day or so, with the following error.  I'm running Tomcat 8.5.31.0 and Java 1.8.0_221

```
INFO  2019-12-02 06:29:38,609 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] app.AppProxy: Creating request for: https://<MY_PROXIED_URL>
ERROR 2019-12-02 06:29:38,610 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] app.AppProxy: A fatal proxy error occurred.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor138.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.jsp.proxy_jsp.fetchAndPassBackToClient(proxy_jsp.java:113)
        at org.apache.jsp.proxy_jsp._jspService(proxy_jsp.java:982)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at recruitingdashboard.NodeHostnameExposeFilter.doFilter(NodeHostnameExposeFilter.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2033)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1135)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2982)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentType(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:406)
        at org.apache.jsp.proxy_jsp.fetchAndPassBackToClient(proxy_jsp.java:109)
        ... 93 more
```

The portion of the proxy that performs the proxied connection is the following:

```
URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    //con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    //con.setReadTimeout(10000);

    con.setConnectTimeout(0);
    con.setReadTimeout(0);

    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", referer);
    con.setRequestMethod(method);

    if (bytes != null && bytes.length > 0 || method.equals("POST")) {

    if (bytes == null){
        bytes = new byte[0];
    }

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        if (contentType == null || contentType.isEmpty()){
            contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }

        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(bytes);
    }

    if (con!=null){
        if (con.getContentType() != null) clientResponse.setContentType(con.getContentType());
        if (con.getContentEncoding() != null)  clientResponse.addHeader("Content-Encoding", con.getContentEncoding());

        InputStream byteStream;
        if (con.getResponseCode() >= 400 && con.getErrorStream() != null){
            if (ignoreAuthenticationErrors && (con.getResponseCode() == 498 || con.getResponseCode() == 499)) return true;
            byteStream = con.getErrorStream();
        }else{
            byteStream = con.getInputStream();
        }

        clientResponse.setStatus(con.getResponseCode());

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final int length = 5000;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = byteStream.read(bytes, 0, length)) > 0) {
            buffer.write(bytes,0,bytesRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();

        byte[] byteResponse = buffer.toByteArray();
        OutputStream ostream = clientResponse.getOutputStream();
        ostream.write(byteResponse);
        ostream.close();
        byteStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please give the exact versions of Java and Tomcat. Could it be that your server is exhausted after some time because the connections aren't closed correctly ? Check that with a `netstat -an` for example.

Comment: Thanks - I have added exact version numbers.

Comment: I believe connections are consistently closing correctly.  Running netstat -na over the course of some period doesn't show connection counts increasing indefinitely.  They go up and then back down.

Comment: Things stop working after a while typically when a resource exhaustion happens (because of not releasing something). Are you able to count how many successfull requests before the failure happens ? Is it following a pattern ?

Comment: One debug helper is `-Djavax.net.debug=all` . It's going to be verbose but it should give the handshake failure reason.

Comment: Do you have configured an SSL connector in your Tomcat `server.xml` ? One workaround could be to use the openssl rather than the JSSE but I haven't tested in a similar case (JSP as a proxy)

Comment: I don't have the SSL connector because Tomcat is not involved in the SSL connection, I have code within the JSP that makes the outbound SSL connection on behalf of the client.

Comment: As said in a previous comment, enable the debug property and post the whole trace of one failed request. This should lead to identify the failure cause

Comment: OK - I have configured the debug option on one of the nodes and I will await the next set of failures to see what the DEBUG logs tell me.  I'll report back then, thanks!